# Masking a light for shadow texture

Tags: light, shaders, masking

I plan to fake a shadow from a light using a mask (in the area light's material I mixed a black 0 strength emission shader with another one that actually casts light). However, the result is nothing. 
My mask texture is black and white. The shadow is a window frame as it seems. 
Is it possible to do this? if so, how?
[image: windowframe_mask]
[image: light_mat]

Comment: you could texture a spot lamp with the lamps UV coordinates but the shadow cast will converge to the spot of the lamp. Remember that an area lamp is a diffuse source, sampled across its area. So it won't give you a sharp texture like you example. Best way to achieve the effect of a window frame is to build a Gobo or Cookie as described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think textured area lights are not fully supported yet. So currently one of the workarounds is to add another mesh under the lamp and add a transparent material on it with transparency controlled by the mask image (as seen below).

[image]

Another way is to add **Texture Coordinates** node to your existing area lamp material and connect the *Reflection* output to the **Image Texture** *Vector* input, however, that looks kinda strange and not very correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try that. 
I tried putting a small window frame in front of the light but it didn't work :D 
I try this plane stuff.